# How to run a rule for a specific user?

Tags: rules

I want to redirect a specific user when he logs in.

There are 4 users.

Each one must go to a different url.

Under the rule I have
[image: Rule for specific user when logged in]
What do I need to put in for the conditions?

Comment: You can create a role for those users who the rule must be applied for them, then use this role in the condition

Comment: There are 4 individual users who I each want to redirect to their own page. So creating a role for each one would be unnecessary.

Comment: creating role doesn't impose any overload on your website. it was just the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

using "Text comparison" for the condition worked.

[image]

So I created a rule for each specific user.

But rather look to the other answer

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer so that it would be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score -1):

There are many other methods to do it, but I prefer this method,

Try this on your [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

> Events: **User has logged in.**
>
> Condition: **User has role**
>
> Actions: **Page redirect**

Comment: I want to redirect a individual user not one based on a role.

Comment: you can read this similar post .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429767/how-to-redirect-user-to-a-specific-page-after-they-login-if-they-belong-to-a-cer